# Android App : Is there any way to deauthorize a user from android application using facebook SDK 4.3?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

While logging in using facebook login button(SDK 4.3) , email id is a mandatory field required by my app. But in the permissions screen the user can deselect the email permission.But still the login is successful . Is there a way to overcome this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should not be de-authorizing the user for not giving your app permission. It generates a poor user experience and might be against the Facebook policy as you are indirectly spamming the user for permissions if they do not provide it.

Your best bet is to continue without emailID.

You can read the policies in detail here : https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

Comment: Thank you for your answer . I have finally implement it such that I am asking for the denied permissions again . And if the user does not provide the email , he cannot login until he provides the email permission. So I don't deauthorize the user :)

Comment: Perfect, your app should get through the review process in that case. Good luck!